# No highlighting in most pages, reports error when editing

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm in the middle of upgrading a solution from VS2010/MVC3/.Net 4 to VS2012/MVC4/.Net 4.5. The solution has been upgraded using VS2012's project migration tool and I followed [this guide](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2011/12/upgrade-aspnet-mvc-3-project-to-mvc-4.html) to upgrade MVC3 to 4.

At the moment, Razor is giving me problems. Syntax highlighting doesn't appear for anything but the layout page, and when I try to move around in a view I either get the dialog:

> Waiting for a background operation to complete. This dialog will close
>   when the operation completes.

Or I get an error telling me to check the Visual Studio activity log (C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.xml), which led me to this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.HTML.Implementation.Projection.GrowingSpanTracker.EnsureNoOverlap()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.HTML.Implementation.Projection.GrowingSpanTracker.EnsureTrackingPoints()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.HTML.Implementation.Projection.GrowingSpanTracker.OnTextBufferChanged(Object
>   sender, TextContentChangedEventArgs e) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent[TArgs](Object
>   sender, EventHandler`1 eventHandlers, TArgs args)

The Source column of the log says it comes from a "Editor or Editor Extension". I'm running vanilla VS2012 here, with no extensions aside from the first party stuff (Microsoft Web Developer Tools, NuGet Package Manager, and Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript).

**EDIT: Some additional details. If I create a new solution and MVC4 project, add the line:**

```
@RenderSection("title", false)
```

to the layout, and then attempt to define the section in a view:

```
@section title{Stuff}
```

The moment I start typing "Stuff" within the braces I get the same errors/behavior.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Ah, right, my bad. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out whatever changed in Razor made braces a bit more...sensitive. If you have a section defined in your layout like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@RenderSection("title", false) - MyApp</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @RenderSection("css",false)
    </head>
    ...
```

And then, in a view that uses the layout, try to use that section *exactly like this* (make sure you actually type it, don't copy/paste):

```
@model MyApp.Web.Models.HomeIndexModel
@section title {Lovely Title}
```

Razor will throw a fit and toss an error into your Visual Studio activity log. Highlighting and most Intellisense support will also fail to work. After some trial and error, I found that it works fine if you basically never leave the braces on the same line. So, write it like this:

```
@model MyApp.Web.Models.HomeIndexModel
@section title {
    Lovely Title
}
```

And it will work fine.

Comment: It has occurred to me that this could be due to a missing bit when I installed VS2012, since I haven't reproduced this problem on another machine. If anyone else could try this, that'd be awesome.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. If you put a space before and after the title, you can have the braces on the same line, like so:  `@section title { Lovely Title }`

Comment: Also, using the ViewBag might be better than a section for the page title.  `@{ViewBag.Title = "blah title";}` and `<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>`

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I might make them all use the ViewBag.